# Binary Tree Implemetation in C for calculating

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm reading a book about Data structures and I'm getting into trouble with the implementation example of binary tree in that book. The problem is I need to calculate and implement this parse tree below:

> [image]

This is the source code of the example I mentioned above:

> [image]

I've known about trees but I cannot understand what the source code really means because the book I'm reading does not explain each step. I really need the deeper explanation for the source code.
EDIT : You can focus on the loop step, it is the most difficult one for me to understand

Comment: Please be more specific: what step do you need explanation for? Does the book have any verbal explanation?

Comment: @bereal It just gives me the source code following the parse tree so I do not understand anything at all

Comment: That `for` line is annoyingly obfuscated. Move `stackinit()` above that line, and change the `for` to `while (scanf("%1s", &c) != EOF)`, which might be much clearer.

Comment: What does the book chapter say before it shows this tree and the code? What does the book say after the code shown? Perhaps somewhere in that text is an explanation of the algorithm used, and the code shows a possible implementation of it?

Comment: @usr2564301 Not to mention the use of `"%1s"` instead of `" %c"`.

Comment: What the code _does_ (in a mechanical/technical sense) is easy; the challenge is to see, where the isomorphism to a real-life problem is. As far as I can tell, it tries to build a binary tree from a _postfix_ notation (i.e. reverse polnish notation). This has to be described somewhere in the book

Comment: @HoangNam What book is it by the way? What edition of it? What chapter?

Comment: So many issues with this old style code. An obvious one is the check `scanf(...) != EOF` as if the author never looked into the documentation. You might consider to dump this book.

Comment: Actually, Google says that it's from a pretty classical book by Robert Sedgewick, though could be quite an old edition, and there are quite a few paragraphs of explanation (I could only find a German edition online though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code seems to implement the [Reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), i.e. a notation where operators follow their operands. It reads an expression recorded in the RPN and builds the corresponding binary tree. For example, for the tree above the RPN form will be:

```
ABC+DE**F+*
```

The logic is pretty straightforward and is based on a stack that contains nodes of the tree:

- Every time you encounter an operand (i.e. a letter), you create a new leaf node with an operand and push it to the stack.
- Every time you encounter an operator, you create a new operator node, that replaces the two top-most nodes from the stack. The replaced nodes become the new node's children.

In the end, you get the expression tree on the top of the stack.

*Update:* As for the specific lines you mentioned: `z` is a special kind of tree node, a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), that is depicted as a tiny rectangle on the picture. That's a no-value node, which allows you to know when you reach the tree bottom. Another way is just to use a null pointer (the link above compares the approaches).

```
z->l = z; 
z->r = z;
```

is what makes the node it's own child. A sentinel node can also represent an empty tree.

Now in the loop:

```
x->info = c;
x->l = z;
x->r = x;
```

creates a new leaf node (operand nodes don't have children). If we then find than the node is actually an operator, the children are immediately replaced with the operands from the stack.

Comment: Can you explain for me: 1. ``z->l = z; z->r = z``; 2. The similar code like (1) but in the loop ``for``? I cannot understand these lines, actually